# best way to calculate average for each records from million of records with php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hadoop, hive

So I have approximately millions of residence data on mysql with many of variable like age, district, subdistrict, village, full address, jobs, wage, etc.

Now I need to make dashboard with heat maps (using codeigniter) that have average wage for each village from those data. Currently I'm using query with apache hive to export csv from those data.

Currently I have 3 alternatives:

- Create a scheduler service that calculate average wage for each village and move it to another table, so the dashboard only need to load data from the newly created table.
- Direct query to apache hive (I've already read that there's an ODBC driver for hive).
- Using stored procedure that triggered from the dashboard to calculate new value.

I'm still finding the best way to do this. Do you have any better alternatives?

Thanks before,

Comment: I would do a direct query with an intermediate short-lived cache.

Comment: @apokryfos direct query using hive or mysql?

Comment: From what you say the most up to date data will be in hive, so hive . The problem with derived data in a database is keeping it up to date (which is why we avoid storing it and compute it on the fly). The cache bit is there to assume that once you've calculated a value it will be accurate (more or less) for the next X minutes (cache duration).

Comment: Two things ... 1. When calculating average of million records, you can neglect first few thousands record if sorted in ascending way. 2. The first method seems the best one, just create one cron job that calculates and store into another table - and then you can use that on your dashboard. But you should run cron mostly based on the frequency of data change.